# Can I pass or somehow get the orchestrationID that is generated by httpTrigger function in my orchestrationTrigger function in durable functions?

Tags: azure-functions, orchestration, azure-durable-functions

I want to do some logging to SEQ in my durable functions and for that I want some identifier, as httpTrigger function generates an orchestrationID which is unique, So I am thinking of using it in all logs specific to one request. So I am looking for how can i fetch or send it to my other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp25
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        // use b to save orchestrationID

        static string b = "";   

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            //use this to get the orchestrationID from IDurableOrchestrationContext

            string a = context.InstanceId;  
            b = a;
            // Replace "hello" with the name of your Durable Activity Function.
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", "Tokyo"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", "Seattle"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", "London"));
            // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
            return outputs;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1_Hello")]
        public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log, [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter)
        {
            log.LogInformation("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"+b);
            log.LogInformation($"Saying hello to {name}.");
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            // Function input comes from the request content.
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Function1", null);
            log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }
    }
}
```

**Original Answer:**

This orchestrationID is an automatically generated GUID. In httptrigger, you can get it like this:

```
string orchestrationID = await starter.StartNewAsync("YourOrchestrationTriggerName", null);
```

However, please notice that every time you trigger a function, IDurableOrchestrationContext will generate a brand new orchestrationID.

Comment: Thanks for replying, yeah I know that orchestrationId is generated in httpTrigger function, I want it in my other functions: In OrchestrationTrigger function and in Activity function

Comment: @BilalShafqat No problem, this can be achieved. You can set a value in advance, this value is used to store orchestrationId. I will update the answer later.

Comment: @BilalShafqat You can customize a string type field b for storage. In OrchestrationTrigger, you can get this read-only field from IDurableOrchestrationContext, and you can assign it to the field b of the string type just defined. Then in Activity you can get field b, field b is orchestrationId.:)

Comment: @BilalShafqat Happy to help.:)